# Ubuntu install results in NO BOOT DEVICE FOUND

Tags: boot

Hi team I need to install ubuntu alongside with Win10 on PC DELL optiplex 7070 core i5 8Gb RAM with SSD 260GB but when installing I don't get the install alongside with WIN or other system so I decided to install ubuntu alone but when asks to reset and remove the USB and boot up It display the message NO BOOT DEVICE FOUND, I've read a lot in the web but no one gives a solution to install ubuntu in an SSD along with another OS, I'll be glad to hear a real solution, thank you.

Comment: In BIOS, disable the RAID+AHCI mode and go back to AHCI mode for SATA disk operation.

Comment: If your installer does not offer 'install alongside Windows', choose 'Something Else' in Step 6 'Allocate drive space' of  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0  which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.